# How to get the Radio Button values in another page using while loop Concept in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

How to get And Store the Radio Button Values in MysqlDatabase in php using looping concepts

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
     ?>                                       
     <tr><form action="update_attendance.php?amid=<?php$row[0];?>&amp;amname=<?php echo $row[1];?>" method="POST">
       <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo date('d-M-Y'); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>                         
       <td> 
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="Present" checked="checked">Present &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="Permission">Permission</input>
            <input type="radio" name="status" value="Absent">Absent</input>
       </td>
       <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success btn-medium">
       </td>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces a lot of radio buttons named "status". You need to make every group of radio buttons to have unique name.

Probably one of your columns in table that you are querying on it is **id** column that is unique.

You can set the `id` (that maybe is `$row[0]` in this case) in the name of input like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $row[0] ?>]" value="a">a</input>
<input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $row[0] ?>]" value="b">b</input>
<input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $row[0] ?>]" value="c">c</input>
```

And in your php file after form submit check `var_dump($_POST['status'])`. You will see that all values are available as an array.